# How to check if I have migrated to AndroidX?

Tags: android, react-native, androidx, migrate

I just created an app with react-native 0.60 and I want to know if I still have to migrate to androidx or thats done automatically when using RN 0.60?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to check if I have migrated to AndroidX?

If you are using [**`React Native 0.60`**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60) then you don't need to  migrate to androidx

Because `React Native 0.60`  has been migrated over to AndroidX.

> Read from docs

[AndroidX Support](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#androidx-support)

- AndroidX is a major step forward in the Android ecosystem, and the old support library artifacts are being deprecated. For 0.60, React Native has been migrated over to AndroidX. This is a breaking change, and your native code and dependencies will need to be migrated as well.